# how to set initial route screens in stacknaviagtor React native?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, stack-navigator

If user already loggedin for app,the initial screen should be home screen with stack navigator. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

in case you are using React Navigation in your app, there is a complete flow right here:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

i think you have to change some part of it due to using redux. hope it helps :)